# Query where relation does not exists with has_one, belongs_to relation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following models :

Sales :

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :vehicle
end
```

Vehicles :

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sale
end
```

And I'd like to query all vehicles that are not associated to a sale, how can I do that ? I've searched the documentation but I haven't found it, maybe I've missed something ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`Vehicle.where(sale: nil)` should do.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Vehicle.where(sale_id: nil)` assuming OP's foreign key for `belongs_to` association `sale` is setup following rails convention?

Comment: That should work, too. But it's more of the "Rails 3" style I think, the new docs usually use the above method. See the `Article.where(author: author)` example around here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions

Comment: This isn't working since the sale_id si in the Sale table not the Vehice. `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column vehicles.sale_id does not exist`

Comment: Then you have set up your model relations incorrectly. `belongs_to` has to be where the `..._id` field is. If your vehicle should belong to a sale then `sale_id` needs to be in the `vehicles` table.

Comment: Putting a `sale_id` into the `sales` table doesn't make any sense since theres already an `id` field in sales by default and the `sales_id` field would reference itself. This way it would be impossible to find the connection between the two. The only alternative where an `..._id` field would be on the  sales table is to alter the `has_one :vehicle` to `belongs_to :vehicle` and change the `sale_id` field on the vehicles table to `vehicle_id`. Also don't forget to update `belongs_to :sale` to be `has_one :sale` if you want to use this approach.

Comment: Refer to the official documentation here for more information: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association In the example there please take note that the `author_id` is on the books table, not on the authors table.